# C, assign char to char array: invalid conversion

Tags: c

```
char buffA[100];
char plan[3][1];
char value[5];

strcpy(value, &buffA[2]);
strcat(value, &buffA[3]);
plan[0][0] = value;
```

`error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'`

How is this correctly done? ive also tried `char *value` but that throws precision loss warning

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the last statement?

Comment: What do you want to do? "Assign char to char array" doesn't make sense to me. One is a char, the other is an array - how can you assign one to the other? Maybe assign the `char` to the first element of the array? Or to all elements?

Comment: The chances are you'll make `value[5]` overflow by copying parts of `buffA[100]` anyway. `strcpy` might copy up to 98 chars then `strcat` a further possible 97 chars.

Answer (score 2):

`plan[0][0]` is a `char`, but `value` is an array of 5 `char`. You cannot assign array of `char` to single `char`.

Use `strncpy` or `memcpy` function to copy `char` array or try this:

```
// this will only copy 1 character, not whole array.
plan[0][0] = value[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you are trying to copy an array to a single char, but I don't think its your only problem,
I don't know what you tried to achieve but unless you are sure there is \0 in your arrays you will have a buffer overflow in here, 
and even if you are sure I recommend to use the safe functions such as strncmp and strncat.

If you want you can explain what you were trying to do and I will be happy to help.

Good luck